# How do I get the first value from this collection using Linq to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entities

I have the following code.  The foreach at the end is unnecessary because there will only be one row returned.

So how do I grab a value from userGroups without having to loop?

Thanks
Kevin

```
using (kdEntities db = new kdEntities())
        {
            Label lbl = sender as Label;
            IQueryable<UserGroup> userGroups = from UserGroup in db.UserGroups where UserGroup.UgpID == 1 select UserGroup;

            foreach (var group in userGroups)
            {
                lbl.Text = group.UgpDescription;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
userGroups.FirstOrDefault();
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

Use `userGroups.FirstOrDefault();` if there could be multiple values and you are only interested in the First one

Use `userGroups.SingleOrDefault();` if there should be only one value. If there are multiple values an exception will be thrown.

The `OrDefault` part is also optional. This will return the default value (in your case `null`) if there is no value. If you leave out `OrDefault` and the collection is empty an exception will be thrown.